# I cannot acces service accounts tab in Firebase console

Tags: firebase, service-accounts

While developing my app, I needed to acces the service accounts tab.
The problem is that it isn't letting me enter the tab.

I've tried entering a direct URL (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/*projectname*/settings/**serviceaccounts**)

and clicking on multiple buttons that should also lead me to that tab, but they gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clear your browser cache**: Sometimes clearing your browser cache can help resolve issues with Firebase project settings. Try clearing your cache and refreshing the page.

**Use a different browser or device**: If clearing your cache doesn't work, try accessing the Service Accounts tab from a different browser or device to see if the issue is related to your current setup.

Comment: Thanks! Clearing the cache didn't quite work. But then I tried using Microsoft Edge and it worked.